# Using SQL Server 2012 how to iterate through an unknown number of rows and calculate date differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, iteration

I need to calculate the average number of days if there are two or more dates for each ID: the days between date1 and date2, date2 and date3 etc. The output needs to be the average number of days between each interval per ID. I am looking for a solution that iterates through each date for each ID and then averages the number of days

I could create a row number and partition by the id but in the actual data there can be up to 20 rows for each ID.

```
CREATE TABLE #ATABLE(
ID   INTEGER  NOT NULL  
,DATE DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #ATABLE(ID,DATE) VALUES (1,'1/1/2019');
INSERT INTO #ATABLE(ID,DATE) VALUES (2,'1/1/2019');
INSERT INTO #ATABLE(ID,DATE) VALUES (2,'1/10/2019');
INSERT INTO #ATABLE(ID,DATE) VALUES (2,'1/20/2019');
INSERT INTO #ATABLE(ID,DATE) VALUES (2,'1/30/2019');
INSERT INTO #ATABLE(ID,DATE) VALUES (3,'1/1/2019');
INSERT INTO #ATABLE(ID,DATE) VALUES (3,'1/10/2019');

--get avg days between orders

DROP TABLE #ATABLE
```

The out put for the above would be:

```
ID  AvgDatediff
1   Null
2   10
3   9
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to stop thinking that SQL Server (and other RDBMS) are an application as well. You shuold *avoid* iteration as much as possible in SQL Server, it's awful at it. SQL Server works best with set based methods, and this seems like it could easily be achieved with a set method and a function like `LEAD`/`LAG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` to get the previous row (per row), and then find the diff between it and the current row. Then, you can average them out:

```
SELECT   id, AVG(diff)
FROM     (SELECT id,
                 DATEDIFF(DAY, date, LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                                     ORDER BY date DESC)) AS diff
          FROM #atable) t
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the average difference is:

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(date), MAX(date)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0)
FROM  #atable) t
GROUP BY id;
```

Note:  You may want a `* 1.0` if you don't want an integer average.

In other words, the average difference is the latest date minus the earliest date divided by one less than the count.  Try it.  It works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, AVG(DayDiff)
FROM (
    SELECT id,
    DATEDIFF(dd, date, LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)) AS DayDiff
    FROM #atable
) as AA
GROUP BY id;
```

`LEAD(source_column)` ==>  picks the next data on basis of the order by clause i.e. here date.